# Logical consequence of Euclid's theorem

Tags: reference-request, logic, soft-question, prime-numbers

Are there any far reaching non-trivial consequences of Euclid's infinitude of primes where theorems make use of it? [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem) does not have the list of applications of this theorem, rather modern proofs of this theorem.

Comment: Number theory and the possibility of prime-based encryption schemes? Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: **Theorem:** There are infinitely many fields with trivial automorphism group.

Comment: @Dan No you understood right; I did not realize that an entire field of cryptography is based on this theorem: http://carlossicoli.free.fr/M/Mollin_R.A.-An_Introduction_to_Cryptography-Chapman_&_Hall%282006%29.pdf

Comment: @Mahmud: Yeah it's definitely useful there. Algorithms like RSA would be pretty useless without infinitely-many primes. :)

Comment: I doubt there would be a problem with any application if there were primes with about the right distribution up to say $10^{10000}$, and then no more.

Comment: Have you thought that if primes were not infinite, then natural numbers would not be infinite (as a consequence of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic)? Can we imagine how far-reaching would be to have a mathematical system where the natural numbers would be finite? Or, can we imagine how different the mathematical system would be if natural numbers were infinite but they were not uniquely factorized into a product of primes (since primes would be finite)? I believe this surpasses our imagination -and this is a good intuitive definition of "far-reaching".

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I actually did think in a similar manner. Intuitively, if there is an endless supply of prime numbers, then one can always find a prime number which cannot be compressed and written given all the particles in the universe. Am I off? So a better question would have been: is there a Kolmogorov complexity of prime numbers?

Comment: "application" is not a math word !

Comment: Kolmogorov complexity is defined for strings of infinite length, so I guess one could work out something for the primes also.

Comment: Gödel numbering-like methods may rely on the infinitude of the set of primes